# prefab does not work same as its origin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class green : MonoBehaviour
{    
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BLUE")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

            gm.mylife -= 1;
        }
    }
}

public class gm : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public GameObject blue;
    static public bool tr = false;
    public Text life;
    public static int mylife = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        makebox();      
    }

   void makebox()
   {
        StartCoroutine("timedelay");
   }             

   IEnumerator timedelay()
   {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
       Debug.Log("sdfaDF");
       GameObject br = Instantiate(blue, new Vector3(-6, -2, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
       makebox();
   }

   void Update()
   {
       life.text = (mylife.ToString());

   }
}
```

I made a blue box which is destroyed when it meets something and has -1 score. 
And it is made at (-2,2)position . 
Then I made a prefab. But the prefab does not work as its origin. It is JUST created at the same position as its origin. 
I want to make my prefab destroy and score -1 also. 
How can i fix it ? 
PLEASE HELP ME...

Answer (score 0):

You are spawning the object at same position all the time:

```
GameObject br = Instantiate(blue, new Vector3(-6, -2, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Instead you should give a new position every time like this:

```
public Vector3 offSet = new Vector3(2,0,0);
Vector3 pos;
IEnumerator timedelay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    Debug.Log("sdfaDF");
    GameObject br = Instantiate(blue, pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    pos += offSet;
    makebox();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help...but so, i gave the delay... maybe it could be solved that give a tag to the cloned prefab... i checked that cloned prefab does not have a tag... ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

GameObject blue = Instantiate(bluep);
 blue.tag = "BLUE";

I solved by giving tag to the object at the script.